# Does Aircon need regassing after change of condenser?

Tags: ac, mini-one

I’m told the A.C. on a Mini Countryman 2013 needs the condenser replacing, but I just had the A.C. regassed prior to this 3 days prior). Will the A.C. need regassing after the condenser is replaced? Many thanks for the advice!

Comment: What is wrong with the condenser? If it has a hole then the refrigerant is already long gone and you will be paying for more.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, the replacement of the condenser involves opening up the refrigerant circuit. A qualified technician will evacuate the system and retain the refrigerant. It's possible that he or she will be able to re-use and add any additional refrigerant required, reducing some cost, possibly. The estimate for the repair should include this process.